# How to delete the whitespace from outputted mysql data

Tags: php, html

[image: code]

How do i trim the whitespace?  I already tried trim() but it doesn't work. this anchor tag data is comming from the database (there are no whitespaces in database table)

Comment: Which part of the output comes from the table?

Comment: aww this is embarrassing, it was indd  a tab! thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: it is data from 4 tables, department, section,category, id

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
function remove_internal_whitespace($string) 
{ 
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string); 
    $string = trim($string); 
    return $string;
}
```

Usage :

```
echo remove_internal_whitespace(your html string here);
```